# What are the semantic functions of a complementizer phrase (CP)

Tags: syntax, english, semantics, pragmatics

What does semantic functions mean? and what are they for a CP?

Thank you

Comment: Agent, theme, recipient and so on.

Comment: "complementizer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None.  The only difference between a CP and the phrase from which it is derived is syntactic.  For instance, the sense of the relative clause in

> Maude was naughty, which surprised us all.

is, replacing the "which" by its antecedent,

> [Maude was naughty] surprised us all.

which is not grammatical only because a sentence cannot be the subject of a sentence.  This is a syntactic requirement.  Without any change to the meaning, if we just add the complementizer "that" as syntactic sugar[(q.v.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), we get the acceptable

> That Maude was naughty surprised us all.